# Space Exploration Logo Proposals

Tags: discussion, theme

Please post as answers below, your logo proposals for this site.

**Rules:**

- Original artwork only.
- You need to have a copy of your submission in a vector format.

---

Following the same suggested format from **[here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/logo-proposals-for-gaming)**.

Comment: Given that the to early comments at http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/221/does-space-exploration-want-need-a-theme I think the same applies to the logo question

Comment: I don't think we should close this off because we can accept suggestions until we are ready for the change. Then we can vote.

Comment: If anyone has an idea they can sketch out but is not comfortable working with vector formats, I'd be happy to convert a raster drawing to vector for them.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Proposed Logo]

The canvas colour represents the cosmic background. At the right bottom are Sol, Luna, and Earth. Sol at the back, Earth, and Luna in front. The small square is the Solar System local space - paths are least bent. Beyond the Solar System, all paths are bent.

EDIT: IMO Space is colourless/black in the absence of light. My selected colour for the background is purple-gray

p.s. So how do I convert this to a Vector Format?

Comment: Is the colour just some arbitrarily chosen one, or is there some evidence for being the colour of the cosmic background? I'm asking, because it would be nice we establish a colour scheme that's relevant in as wider sense as possible. For example, there is the [Cosmic Latte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_latte). I think it could go well with this one used here. As for converting to vector - if you draw it as a raster (no layers in 2D, views in 3D,...) then there is no direct way but to reconstruct it with the help of the raster image. ;)

Comment: I would checkout inkscape if you are interested in creating vector formats. I'm not exactly sure if there is an easy way "converting" with week line thickness like this.