# Revisiting a Space Exploration theme?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, theme

There have been a [few proposals](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/does-space-exploration-want-need-a-theme) in [the past](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/773/can-we-get-a-picture-for-the-space-exploration-stackexchange-site) [suggesting/asking](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/space-exploration-logo-proposals) for a theme for [this site](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/why-doesnt-space-se-have-an-icon).  Most were made back when graduating from beta was enough to warrant a site-specific Icon.  We have now been [out of beta for almost 18 months](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/graduation-of-space-exploration), but unfortunately, the requirements for getting a [site-specific logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) have increased as well.

However, I believe it is time for us to start thinking about this again.  A pastel-blue speech bubble with "SX" emblazoned on it doesn't exactly scream "SPACE EXPLORATION," the way a **black bubble with a Sputnik on it*** would.

Comments to the [latest post](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/now-that-the-site-has-graduated-how-do-we-get-a-site-specific-icon) on this topic suggest that a high degree of persistence is key to getting a site logo now.
My thoughts are: "Well that's not exactly rocket science?"

What do you think?

---

*My preferred logo

Comment: I'm not certain asking explicitly will change the schedule that SE has for sites. I understand they get to each site when they get to it. I moderate 8 sites - 4 have themes, 4 don't, but the timing on each is driven from SE